# In Yii2 ActiveQuery, create a query with only the related objects?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I've got an `ActiveModel` class called `UserActivity` that returns an `ActiveQuery` to the related `User` table.

I want to return an `ActiveDataProvider` with a query that lists *these* users, **filtered** by criteria on a `UserActivity` query.

My `UserActivity` class looks somewhat like this:

```
class UserActivity extends ActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public function getUser(){
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(),["id"=>"id_user"]);
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm returning an `ActiveDataProvider` in my Yii2 REST API (for it's automatic paging), and I can return a query on my `GetLikingUsers` action like this:

```
...
public function run($type){
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => UserActivity::find()->where(["type"=>$type]),
    ]);
}
...
```

... but this returns me objects of `UserActivity` type, which I don't want to expose through the API. I'd rather only send the matching users, something like:

```
...
public function run($type){
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => UserActivity::find()->where(["type"=>$type])->getUser(),
    ]);
}
...
```

but this does not work, of course. I know I can eager-load using `with("user")` on the query, and I could send it along with `UserActivity` but my problem is that I don't want API consumers to know what the `UserActivity` type is, they should be concerned with only the `User` type.

I like using ActiveQuery, and my API has been forming up nicely, so far, but I'm stuck with this.

Comment: Either modify this data provider to return users related to UserActivity (not the other way around) or iterate the results of your original provider and send only the desired output.

Comment: @Bizley so you're saying I should start my query with the `User` object, and make relations as required to get the query filtered the way I want?

Comment: If you want User model to be returned - yes, that's one way to do it.